# Create folder in jar file dir

Tags: java, logging, jar

Im looking for a solution to create a new folder in the folder, where the .jar file is located.

So if i have a test.jer file in `C:\test\temp` I would like to be able to create a new folder (newFolder) : `C:\test\temp\newFolder.`

Anyone know how to do this.
I have tried to use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir").
```

But this only gives me the correct, if i double click the jar file.
I need it to be run from a scheduler and then the location is changed.

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot easily figure out where your JAR file is at runtime. The execution environment of your VM can tell you the user directory (as you said), but that is the directory from which the VM was started. So if you double click your JAR, that's actually the directory where the JAR is. But if you call java on the commandline, for example

> c:\some\directory> java -cp c:\temp\test.jar main.Class

then "user.dir" will contain "c:\some\directory". 
This lack of information is intentional, because it allows the VM to transparently load classes from different locations.

Your best choice to do what you want would be to pass the directory of choice as a commandline argument. And in the worst case, you could use "user.dir" as default. But what the best solution really is depends on why you want to place the directory where the JAR is.

Comment: My problem in a nutshall. "user.dir" is in my case the dir of the scheduler tool calling the jar file

The problem is the placement of logs.
I want to place the log, along with the jar file.

The jar file is running as a scheduled task. all tasks are placed in their own folder, with the following log. But the service have to be distubuted across different machines.

So the same program have to place logs different places. But it always have to place them acording to the placement of the jar file.

Makes sense?

Comment: Didn't find a solution. Ended up taking the jar file lacation as a cmd argument.